# Disable Specific DIV when updateprogress is in progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, updateprogress

Hi I Have 3 Div in my webpage.

I Want to disable only one div of my webpage when updateprogress is in progress.

I Want rest two div will be enabled wen updateprogress is in progress.

```
<div id="blur">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="progress">

   <%-- Update in progress. Please wait ...--%>

</div>
```

```
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: show code. what have you tried? have you heard of javascript?

Comment: m not using javascript..

Comment: if u have solution with java script , u can suggest

Comment: simply suppose  i have two div's. while Update Progress is in progress

Comment: how do you start / end process for updating? in general you can add some JS-Function or event to "start Progress"... what happens when the progress is finished? How do you update?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on some assumptions. For instance, you have a place to put JavaScript and a possibility to trigger it. Also i assume your Update will get handled separately and also has a way to call JS.

simple JS (put in `<script>`-Tags):

```
var startProgress = new function(){
    document.getElementById("progress").disable; //or do whatever else...
    //Start your progress
    }

var finished = new function(){
    document.getElementById("progress").enable; //revert whatever you did...
    //do other things you want to do when finished...
    }
```

You would have to do something like this in you triggering control

```
<asp:Button ID="trigger" onClick="startProgress" Value="Update" />
```

When you click your trigger, your Javascript will get searched for `startProgress`. This function crawls your whole document and matches the first element with `id="progress"` and disables it.

On your callback / update you would then call `finished` to enable the div again